# Using Sockets & GameKit at the same time. Drastic socket speed reduction

Tags: ios, sockets, xamarin.ios, gamekit

I've encountered a pretty large issue and have been trying to find a solution for 2 months now with no luck. I've submitted it as a bug, ( https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4910 )  but was hoping maybe someone here could shed some light on the cause of the problem, or suggest a work-around.

In a nutshell, to encounter the error:

1. Create a basic .Net socket connection between two devices
2. Create and initialize a GameKit.GKSession object on a least one device.

What occurs is the transfer of the data on the .NET socket becomes erratic and too slow to be usable. I've performed many tests across different devices (see link below) and it affects all of them (iPad 3 affected the least). I've tested it between an iPhone and a Windows PC and it still occurs. MonoTouch's GameKit code is somehow affecting the Socket code.
As you can see from the spreadsheet, speed drop from a few milliseconds to send 1 MB to several minutes to forever.
As soon as the GameKit.GKSession is set to null, any backedlogged data on the socket flows freely again and the sockets act normally once more.

Sample Windows and iOS/MonoTouch Apps demonstrating problem: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8617393/SocketBug/SocketBug.zip

Test results across different devices (PDF Spreadsheet): 
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8617393/SocketBug/SocketBugTestResults.pdf

Comment: Are you sure this is MonoTouch and not GameKit itself?

Comment: I really have no idea. They are both black boxes to me. There is some conflict between the two. I have scoured the internet looking for others with similar problem to this with GameKit in Objective C and have found nothing. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assist with anyone that comes across this problem, the issue only manifests itself when the GKSession.Available is set to true. This is required for the device to be discoverable, but not to maintain a connection. With this in mind, a temporary work-around can be used where the GKSession.Available is only set to true when required, and set to false as soon as the connection has been made.

In my scenario, I have a socket connection to the server on both devices. I use this connection to send a message from device A to device B, asking it to become discoverable via bluetooth for the next 10 seconds. As soon as the message is sent, device A begins looking for device B and connects as soon as it finds it. Once the connection is established (or 10 seconds elapses without a connection), device B turns off discoverability and the socket behaves as normal.

In my circumstances, this is an acceptable (pending no real fix) workaround to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems so hard even Apple decided to circumvent it: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1753/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011315

The revealing sentence is this: "This change was made to reduce interference with Wi-Fi."